# How can I calculate pos_weight variable of the tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits for multiple classes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to use `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

There are three classes of the dataset. The number of images in `class A is 5500`, in `class B is 2000`, and in `class C is 20000`.

How can I calculate and use `pos_weight` variable in `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`?

Answer (score 0):

The function `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` is implementing binary cross entropy loss. The loss you are looking for is a "categorical" cross entropy. And if you are looking for a concrete behaviour I recommend you to implement it from scratch.
Here you have what you are asking for:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
>>> # Weighted categorical cross entropy
>>> def ce(y_pred, y_true, weights):
...   y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, 1e-6, 1 - 1e-6)
...   loss = -tf.math.log(y_pred)
...   loss = y_true * loss
...   loss = weights * loss
...   return tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(loss, axis=1))
>>>
# A B C just refers to your classes
>>> weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', [A, B, C], y_true)
>>> y_true = tf.one_hot(y_true, NUM_CLASSES)
>>> y_pred = tf.random.uniform((3, 3)) # Mock predictions (Should be activated by a softmax)
>>> print(y_true.shape, y_pred.shape)
(3, 3) (3, 3)
>>> ce(y_pred, y_true, weights)
<tf.Tensor: id=23, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.8649616>
```